# Stored procedure exeuction plan of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-execution-plan

I know that the SQL Server creates an execution plan of stored procedure when it runs for the first time. And then would then be reused again and again until It is recompiled.

If there is the following stored procedure and I execute that with parameter 'A' for the first time, do the rest queries(the rest parameters except 'A') work inefficiently because of the execute plan that already fitted for only 'A'?

```
CREATE PROC SP_TEST 
    @FLAG NVARCHAR(5)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@FLAG = 'A')
    BEGIN
        SELECT ... 
        FROM A_TABLE

        UPDATE ... 
        FROM A_TABLE

        INSERT ... 
        FROM A_TABLE
    END  -- IF (@FLAG = 'A')
    ELSE IF (@FLAG = 'B')
    BEGIN
        SELECT ... 
        FROM B_TABLE

        UPDATE ... 
        FROM B_TABLE

        INSERT ... 
        FROM B_TABLE
    END   -- ELSE IF (@FLAG = 'B')
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT ... 
        FROM TABLE

        UPDATE ... 
        FROM TABLE

        INSERT ... 
        FROM TABLE
    END   -- ELSE
END
```

Comment: Suggest you give Erland's discussion of [performance mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) a look. And I really REALLY hope you don't write procedures like this. A procedure should be a single unit-of-code that has a specific purpose. This <kitchen sink> approach is not a good pattern to follow for many reasons.

Comment: Thanks! I just wonder it because I use both ot databases(sql-server, oracle). but sometime I can see the PL/SQL included a lot of parts with 'IF' in Oracle. that's why I want to know about it surely in terms of sql-server.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Also it's not correct to say that the stored procedure has an execution plan. Each statement in the stored procedure has its own execution plan so in your example case there would be nine separate plans (one for each select/update/insert statement) for each combination of @@OPTIONS used at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, Can you explain the @@options in detail If you don't mind? In fact, I found it on the MS doc as soon as I saw this, but I didn't understand it fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called as Parameter sniffing and if you have skewed data for a particular column (e.g Icecream choice. Many persons would have Vannila as the choice, there will be less number of values for Strawberry, Chocolate etc). If first query was for Strawberry, the plan will be prepared for strawberry.

```sql
CREATE NON CLUSTERED INDEX idx_Icecreamchoice on dbo.Employee(Icecreamchoice) 

--The below query might use bookmark lookup, which is fine, as there will be less IO

SELECT EmployeeName, ... FROM Employee WHERE IcecreamChoice = 'Strawberry'
```

But, due to parameter sniffing, the below query will also try to use bookmark lookup, which will lead to more IO and lead to poor performance.

```sql
SELECT EmployeeName, ... FROM Employee WHERE IcecreamChoice = 'Vannilla'
```

We need to go for RECOMPILE option to avoid these scenarios. We can go for statement level recompile also.

```
SELECT EmployeeName, ... FROM Employee WHERE IcecreamChoice = 'Vannilla' option (recompile)
```

In your question, as you are having IF ELSE logic for the flag, there will be different paths for different flags and so, it would not cause parameter sniffing problem. They are accessing different set of tables.

```
BEGIN
    IF (@FLAG = 'A') -- PATH 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT ... 
        FROM A_TABLE

        UPDATE ... 
        FROM A_TABLE

        INSERT ... 
        FROM A_TABLE
    END  -- IF (@FLAG = 'A')
    ELSE IF (@FLAG = 'B') -- PATH 2
    BEGIN
        SELECT ... 
        FROM B_TABLE

        UPDATE ... 
        FROM B_TABLE

        INSERT ... 
        FROM B_TABLE
    END   -- ELSE IF (@FLAG = 'B')
    ELSE  -- PATH 3
    BEGIN
        SELECT ... 
        FROM TABLE

        UPDATE ... 
        FROM TABLE

        INSERT ... 
        FROM TABLE
    END   -- ELSE
```